# How many time does knitr takes do export a html file in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

This is me again asking a noob question.
I writed a code in R Markdown file to export results in html. All chunks runs just fine in R. But, when I click 'knit' button, the system hangs for a long time processing de file and get stucked at the 3rd chunk. I've already waited for an entire hour but there's no progress and don't give me any error message. This is the first "big" base I'm working, with 21k lines and 69 columns. I don't know if it is normal for this size of data or maybe I'm missing any detail. The data base is hosted in my drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WfYiq2GOUheN9y_rSaSumbp_rIYIiQVb/view?usp=sharing and the code and the processing progress follows here:

````
  
    ---
    title: "exer2_Renato_Fred"
    output:
      pdf_document: default
      html_document: default
    ---
    <style>
    body {
    text-align: justify}
    </style>

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE)
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(results = 'hide')
    library(data.table)
    library(foreign)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(jtools)
    library(readxl)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(lmtest)
    library(sandwich)
    library(lfe)
    library(huxtable)
    ```
    ```{r , echo=FALSE}
    setwd("D:/Google Drive/Mestrado 2020/Econometria Aplicada I/Aula_3-PooledOls")
    local <- getwd()
    arquivo <- paste0(local,"/Base.xlsx")
    tabela <- read_xlsx(arquivo)
    tabela <- data.table(tabela, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
    ```

    ```{r, echo=FALSE}
    levels(factor(tabela$setoreconomtica))
    ggplot(tabela,aes(tabela$corporategovernancelevel,tabela$netprofit))+geom_point()
    ```
    
    ```{r, echo=FALSE}
    tabela[,"tobin" := firmmarketvalue/totalasset]
    tabela[,"roa" := netprofit/totalasset]
    tabela[,"roe" := equity/totalasset]
    tabela[,"dividacp" := shorttermdebt/totalasset]
    tabela[,"dividalp" := longtermdebt/totalasset]
    tabela[,"ieg" := (longtermdebt+shorttermdebt)/totalasset]
    tabela[,quarter := as.factor(quarter)]
    ```
    
    ```{r ,echo=TRUE}
    lmroa <- lm(roa~ieg+dividalp, data=tabela)
    summ(lmroa)
    coeftest(lmroa, df= ,vcov = vcovHC(lmroa,"HC1"))
    #tabela[,corporategovernancelevel := as.factor(corporategovernancelevel)]
    ```
    
    ```{r,echo=TRUE}
    lmroa2 <- lm(roa~ieg+dividalp+quarter, data=tabela)
    summ(lmroa2)
    coeftest(lmroa2, df= ,vcov = vcovHC(lmroa,"HC1"))
    ```
    
    ```{r,echo=TRUE}
    tabela$quarter <- relevel(tabela$quarter,ref="1")
    lmroa3 <- lm(roa~dividacp+quarter, data = tabela)
    summ(lmroa3, robust = "HC1", confint = T, digits=5)
    coeftest(lmroa3, df= ,vcov = vcovHC(lmroa,"HC1"))
    felmroa <- felm(roa~dividacp+quarter | setoreconomtica, data=tabela)
    felmroa2 <- felm(roa~dividacp+corporategovernancelevel | setoreconomtica, data=tabela)
    huxreg(lmroa3,felmroa,felmroa2)
    ```
````

---

processing file: exer2_Renato_Fred.Rmd
|.....                                                                 |   8%
ordinary text without R code

|...........                                                           |  15%
label: setup (with options)
List of 1
$ include: logi FALSE

|................                                                      |  23%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options)
List of 1
$ echo: logi FALSE

|......................                                                |  31%
ordinary text without R code

|...........................                                           |  38%
label: unnamed-chunk-2 (with options)
List of 1
$ echo: logi FALSE

|................................                                      |  46%
ordinary text without R code

|......................................                                |  54%
label: unnamed-chunk-3 (with options)
List of 1
$ echo: logi FALSE

after this, nothing happens. I tried to insert the data.table in another chunk and in that chunk the system gets busy. Seems to be something wrong with de columns creation.

Comment: PS: a) while processing, 'R for Windows terminal front-end' is observed in the task manager. b) Other .rmd files runs normal and generates html files. c) cache directory of the graph  rendered in se 2nd chunck is created. d) I reinstalled R and R Studio but had no changes.

Comment: I have not tested if this sorts it but the `ggplot` syntax in the third chunk should be  `ggplot(tabela,aes(corporategovernancelevel, netprofit)) + geom_point()`

Comment: Thank you. It makes the code much more cleaner. But the knitr is still hangin

Comment: To answer your question, it's not normal - something has gone wrong. What happens if you run this code in the R console, line by line? Does it work then?

Comment: It runs just fine, line by line

Comment: You need to find what's making it hang - i.e. reproduce the bug. Start by running it in a clean session (restart, make sure no variables are hanging around, then run line by line). If that still works, run it from the command line with `rmarkdown::render("filename.Rmd")`.

Comment: I didn't figured it out why, but using dplyr (rather than  data.table) to create the columns, knitr doesn't hangs. Like this:  `tabela <- within(tabela, {tobin <- firmmarketvalue/totalasset})`